# How to derive Arrhenius equation from hard-sphere collision theory

Tags: kinetics

Reading the [description of the Arrhenius equation from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation):

> ...One example comes from the collision theory of chemical reactions, developed by Max Trautz and William Lewis in the years 1916-18. In this theory, molecules are supposed to react if they collide with a relative kinetic energy along their lines-of-center that exceeds Ea. This leads to an expression very similar to the Arrhenius equation.

I was wondering how to derive the Arrhenius equation from the mentioned hard-sphere collision theory. I tried to do so but got a totally different expression from the Arrhenius equation. The original derivation [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/zaac.19160960102) written by Max Trautz seems to be in German, but I cannot read German. Does anyone know how to do the derivation?

Comment: Reading German physics stuff isn't rocket science, for someone who's fluent in physical English. Give it a try! ;-)